# HTML js how to check if name exists in list ignoring case and to stop form submission

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form with an input field for the username to check if the field is empty and to check if what the user entered exists on a list.

This half works as in the messages appear when invalid however the form still submits if the user enters a name that exists in the list where as the form does not submit when the field is blank (but this is due to the input required tag being present).

Also if the user enters a name that exists in the list but with different case letters the message 'The name already exists' does not appear as it does not match the case of the name in the list.

Please see my code below:

```
<script>
function usernameFunction() {
  let x = document.getElementsByName("username")[0].value;
  let listNames = ["john", "sid", "paul", "jim"];

  let text;
  text = "";
  if (x === '' ||  x == null) {
    text = "Username cannot be blank";
  }
    for (let i = 0; i < listNames.length; i++) {
    if (listNames[i] === x) {
      text = ('The name already exists')
    }
  }

  document.getElementById("username_errors").innerHTML = text;
}
document.addEventListener('invalid', (function () {
  return function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    document.getElementsByName("username").focus();

  };
})(), true);
</script>

<form method="POST" action="">
<input type="text" name="username"  placeholder="username" name class="input_fields" required>
<div class="error-message" id="username_errors"></div>
      <input class="save_btn" type="submit" value="Save" name="save_username" onclick="usernameFunction()">
</form>
```

How can I adapt my code to stop submission of the form when the name exists in the list and ignoring the case? - for example - john being in the list if the user enters John, I would like the message 'The name already exists' to still appear and to not submit.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `x == null` won't every be true as `.value` will always return a string (if `document.getElementsByName("username")[0]` exists).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be the line for you:

```
 if ( listNames.includes(x.toLowerCase()) ) {
    return false;
  }
```

It check if the value `John` is included in the array of names. And the String Function `toLowerCase()` make morph the name to lowercase.

### UPDATE

```js
function usernameFunction(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  
  let text = '';
  let x = document.getElementsByName("username")[0].value;
  let listNames = ["john", "sid", "paul", "jim"];
  if ( listNames.includes(x.toLowerCase()) ) {
    text = x + ' allready taken.';    
  }
  if (x === '' ||  x == null) {
    text = "Username cannot be blank";
  }
  
  if (text.length > 0) {
    document.getElementById("username_errors").innerHTML = text;  
    return false;
  }
  // trigger Submit programmatically
  document.getElementById("myForm").submit(); 
  console.log('trigger submit')  
}

document.addEventListener('invalid', (function () {
  return function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    document.getElementsByName("username").focus();

  };
})(), true);
```

```html
<form method="POST" id="myForm">
<input type="text" name="username" value="John" placeholder="username" name class="input_fields" required>
<div class="error-message" id="username_errors"></div>
<button class="save_btn" onclick="usernameFunction(event)">SUBMIT</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you for this, ignoring case now works - but when the popup message appears name exists and i click ok it seems the form is still submitting is there a way to stop this just like the input required tag does for when the input field is blank?

Comment: @Jimmy Yes. I have modified my answer. The reason it sends the form is because of the input submit field. I have replaced it with a button and submit the form programmatically when all conditions are met.

Comment: Thank you so much works just as I wanted - hopefully i will be able to use this for other fields and adapt. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `toUpperCase()` for this.

```
if (listNames[i].toUpperCase() === x.toUpperCase())
 {
  text = ('The name already exists')
}
```